# Слушатель ScrollView вешается на все ScrollView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-scrollview

В  test1.xml есть ScrollView в коде создаётся слушатель` scrollViewTest2 = (ScrollView) MainActivity.mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.ScrollViewTest2);

```
            ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener ScrollChangeTest2 = new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    System.out.println("SCROLLVIEW");
                }
            };

            scrollViewTest2.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(ScrollChangeContact);`
```

Затем перекидываюсь на второй экран test2.xml , где есть другой ScrollView  и при его прокрутке печатается SCROLLVIEW ,  то есть отрабатывает слушатель для другого ScrollView , как исправить это?